# Jupyter Notebook gets killed when using MaxPool layers

Tags: tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook

I am training a neural-net model using Keras-CPU. It works fine when I don't add any `MaxPool` layers, but my jupyter kernel dies whenever I use a `MaxPool` layer.

My whole data size is around *480* MB. My system has 128GB of memory, and it doesn't take more than 5-10 GB of memory when ran without `MaxPool` layers. My batch size is also small (32), and there is no significant increase in memory usage when I run the training.

CPU usage goes up for a few seconds and then it drops back. There is an attached metric regarding the info of a single epoch; it just prints the start of the epochs:

> Epoch 1/2

and after that, my kernel dies.

Here is the architecture of the network:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 382)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
embedding_1 (Embedding)      (None, 382, 100)          490600    
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_1 (Conv1D)            (None, 382, 64)           12864     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_1 (MaxPooling1 (None, 191, 64)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_2 (Conv1D)            (None, 191, 128)          16512     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_2 (MaxPooling1 (None, 95, 128)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 12160)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 64)                778304    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 64)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 128)               8320      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 129       
=================================================================
Total params: 1,306,729
Trainable params: 1,306,729
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Here is the method where I train my neural network:

```py
def get_nnn(train_data_shape, max_val, emb_shape, drop_out, pre_batch_size, pre_batch_epoch,\
           final_batch_size, final_batch_epoch, ls_start, lr_end,class_weight, lr_decay_pat,\
                      lr_decay_rat,num_conv,conv_kernels,conv_neurons,train_data,                              train_lbl,test_data,test_lbl,loss_type='binary_crossentropy',\
           act='sigmoid',use_emb=True,use_max_pool=True,custom_methods=[]):

    #A lot of params

    nnet = Input(shape=(train_data_shape,))
    inp = nnet

    if use_emb:
        nnet = Embedding(max_val+1, emb_shape)(nnet)

    for i in range(num_conv):
        nnet = Conv1D(conv_neurons[i],conv_kernels[i], padding='same',activation='relu')(nnet)
        if use_max_pool:
            #Adding MaxPool here
            nnet = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(nnet)
    nnet = Flatten()(nnet)
    nnet = Dense(64, activation='relu')(nnet)
    nnet = Dropout(drop_out)(nnet)
    nnet = Dense(128, activation='relu')(nnet)

    batch_size = final_batch_size
    epochs = final_batch_epoch

    lentrain = train_data.shape[0]

    exp_decay = lambda init, fin, steps: (init/fin)**(1/(steps-1)) - 1
    steps = int(lentrain / batch_size) * epochs
    lr_init, lr_fin = ls_start, lr_end
    lr_decay = exp_decay(lr_init, lr_fin, steps)

    output = Dense(1, activation=act)(nnet)
    model = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=output)


    model.compile(loss=loss_type, optimizer=Adam(lr=ls_start, decay=lr_decay),
                  metrics=['accuracy',precisioned,recalled,f1]+custom_methods)


    reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=lr_decay_rat,
                              patience=lr_decay_pat, min_lr=lr_end)


    print(model.summary())

    model.fit(train_data, train_lbl,
              epochs=pre_batch_epoch,
              batch_size=pre_batch_size,
              class_weight=class_weight,
              validation_data=(test_data, test_lbl),
              callbacks=[reduce_lr])

    model.fit(train_data, train_lbl,
              epochs=epochs,
              batch_size=batch_size,
              class_weight=class_weight,
              validation_data=(test_data, test_lbl),
              callbacks=[reduce_lr])

    return model
```

Comment: Please post your code as well.

Comment: I've posted my code.

Comment: I could not find anything wrong with your code (except that you are calling `fit` two times which I don't know why). Have you tried running your python script without using Jupyter (i.e. `python your_script.py`) and see it if it runs without problems? If that's the case, there might be something wrong with the Jupyter installed on your machine.

Comment: I intended to call **fit** 2 times, 1st time with a lower batch size for few epochs, and then with large batch size and more epochs

Comment: In TensorFlow there is an internal 2GB limit for the tf.GraphDef protocol buffer which in most cases raises an OOM (out of memory) error. This could be the reason for freezing your Jupyter kernel. 

Lowering batch_size and/or reducing memory usage by using 16-bit instead of 64/32-bit numbers could help.

Comment: Hey, I ran the same thing using terminal python: this is the error I get https://pastebin.com/Hcp7LeC3